# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los datos en un método que están en un archivo?

Tags: java, poo

¿Cómo puedo mostrar los datos en un método que están en un archivo?
Aquí les dejo las clases para que puedan analizarlo.
No me sale ningún error ni nada, solo quiero que me muestre los datos guardados en el archivo que se creo en mi clase principal.

Método principal

```
ArchTipoVeh archv1 = new ArchTipoVeh("tipoV.dat");
    //archv1.crear();
    Soat s = new Soat();
    s.leerSoat();
    //archv1.adicionar(s);
    archv1.listar(s);
```

Método de un archivo para persistencia

```
public void listar(Soat s) throws Exception{
        ObjectInputStream lector = null;
        
        try {
            lector = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(nomArch));
            while(true) {
                regV = new TipoVehiculo("",s);
                regV = (TipoVehiculo)lector.readObject();
                regV.mostrartipV();
                
                
                }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("----Fin listado!------");
        }finally {
            lector.close();
        }
    }
```

Constructor de la clase que quiero que se muestre

```
public TipoVehiculo(String placa, Soat soat) {
          super(placa,soat);
          tipoVehiculo = "";
          modeloVehiculo = "";
          codVeh = "";
          capacidad = 0 ;
      }
```

Método mostrar

```
public void mostrartipV() {
          
          System.out.println("Tipo de vehiculo : "+this.tipoVehiculo);
          System.out.println("Modelo de Vehiculo: "+ this.modeloVehiculo);
          System.out.println("Capacidad : "+this.capacidad);
          System.out.println("Placa : " +this.placa);
          System.out.println("Fecha de inicio: "+this.s.getFechaInicio());
          System.out.println("Fecha de vencimiento: "+ this.s.getFechaVencimiento());
      }
```

Comment: Hola Hans, bienvenido, es difícil saber, como estás guardando el "vehiculo" en el "txt", si ejecutas tu código, recibes algún mensaje de error?, si es así, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregarlo?.

Comment: ya lo edite, gracias por su respuesta.
Estaré atento a las posibles soluciones.

Comment: En tu código debería haber una linea tipo: **escritor = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( nomArch ));** que es la que escribe en el "txt", la podrías mostrar?.